# Странная сортировка

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Я не знаю почему, но следующий код не сортирует вложенный список по первому элементу списка в порядке возрастания.
Код:

```
a=[['9970.90000', '0.08000000'],
   ['9971.90000', '0.21200000'],
   ['9978.30000', '0.07000000'],
   ['10094.00000', '0.00500000'],
   ['9978.90000', '5.00000000'],
   ['9979.00000', '0.07182000'],
   ['10239', '0.40000000'],
   ['16000', '1.23400000'],
   ['9979.10000', '2.00000000'],
   ['9978.40000', '2.00000000']
    ]

a.sort()
```

и выходит:

```
a=[['10094.00000', '0.00500000'],
 ['10239', '0.40000000'],
 ['16000', '1.23400000'],
 ['9970.90000', '0.08000000'],
 ['9971.90000', '0.21200000'],
 ['9978.30000', '0.07000000'],
 ['9978.40000', '2.00000000'],
 ['9978.90000', '5.00000000'],
 ['9979.00000', '0.07182000'],
 ['9979.10000', '2.00000000']]
```

Почему-то все списки с 4 знаками сортируются по возрастанию, а три списка с 5 знаками появляются на первых местах. В чем же заключается моя ошибка?

Comment: Список списков сортируется по первому элементу. Обратите внимание, что это текст, а не числа. Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Вы сортируете строки, а строки сортируются по алфавиту, и символ `1` в алфавите находится ближе к началу чем символ `9`

Comment: Ага, я что-то проглядел это. Возникает вопрос: можно ли как-то поменять все первые элементы в списках одной командой(если да то какой) или обязательно надо каждый менять через цикл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать параметр `key` с лямбда-функцией:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x:float(x[0]))
```

В итоговом списке вложенные списки будут сортированы по численному значению первого элемента, но останутся строками.